# Problem implementing a trait to multiple types

Tags: rust

As a practice exercise, I'm trying to create a temperature unit library.

Currently, the following code won't compile and the error message is unclear to me. The problem seems to be a type conflict.

```rust
type Fahrenheit = f64;
type Celcius = f64;
type Kelvin = f64;


trait TemperatureUnit {
    fn to_kelvin(&self) -> Kelvin;
}

impl TemperatureUnit for Fahrenheit {
    fn to_kelvin(&self) -> Kelvin {
        (*self + 459.67) * 5/9
    }
}

impl TemperatureUnit for Celcius {
    fn to_kelvin(&self) -> Kelvin {
        *self + 273.15
    } 
}

impl TemperatureUnit for Kelvin {
    fn to_kelvin(&self) -> Kelvin {
        *self
    }
}
```

Errors:

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `TemperatureUnit` for type `f64`
  --> src/lib.rs:18:1
   |
12 | impl TemperatureUnit for Fahrenheit {
   | ----------------------------------- first implementation here
...
18 | impl TemperatureUnit for Celcius {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ conflicting implementation for `f64`

error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `TemperatureUnit` for type `f64`
  --> src/lib.rs:24:1
   |
12 | impl TemperatureUnit for Fahrenheit {
   | ----------------------------------- first implementation here
...
24 | impl TemperatureUnit for Kelvin {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ conflicting implementation for `f64`
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0098114a310ab37d82fba956ac7acede)

I'm new to Rust, so maybe this is not the proper methodology to achieve a compiler-enforced type-safe unit conversion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you write `type`, you're making a type alias, not a new type. It's like when you use `typedef` in C++, for instance.

```
type Fahrenheit = f64;
```

This *literally* says "when I say 'Fahrenheit', pretend I said `f64` instead". Not a new type, not a distinct structure, literally the same. So you just implemented `TemperatureUnit for f64` three times.

If you want to wrap `f64` in a custom type under your control, you're looking for the [*newtype pattern*](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/patterns/patterns/behavioural/newtype.html).

```
pub struct Fahrenheit(pub f64);
```

Now `Fahrenheit` is a distinct structure that happens to be isomorphic to `f64`. You can go from `f64` to `Fahrenheit` with the `Fahrenheit(x)` constructor, and you can go back with the `my_fahrenheit.0` projection. You can also name the projection if you prefer.

```
pub struct Fahrenheit { pub float_repr: f64 };
```

Rust will almost certainly compile this internally to an actual `f64`. Structs with only one field will generally have no overhead. But we can actually guarantee this with [`repr(transparent)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/other-reprs.html#reprtransparent)

```
#[repr(transparent)]
pub struct Fahrenheit(pub f64);
```

This guarantees that, at runtime, `Fahrenheit` and `f64` have the same representation (even to the extent that `transmute` is defined between them), while at compile-time they're distinct types.

The only thing left to decide is what traits you want your new type to implement. It will inherit nothing from `f64` by default, so you'll likely have a massive `derive(...)` clause right before the declaration including `Eq`, `Ord`, `Clone`, `Copy`, etc. (non-exhaustive list; you know your use case better than I do)

Comment: Do not use `#[repr(transparent)]` unless you need it for unsafe code: AFAIK it is actually the same today, and when not I'd expect the default representation to be more performant.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Your answer was clear and complete.
Not sure about the implication of `isomorphic` in a CS context (transmute == inverse mapping ? ).

Comment: @gberth Sorry, category theory brain getting ahead of me. Don't read too much into that. I just mean that the two store the same data. There's a map `Fahrenheit -> f64` and one `f64 -> Fahrenheit` that are inverses of each other.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The rust vocabulary is quite extensive, so I was wondering if I was missing something. :^)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `type` just aliases a type, it doesn't create a new one. Rust is complaining because those three `impl` blocks are trying to implement `TemperatureUnit` on the same type three times.

Instead, you should declare new types. The example below uses `struct`.

[Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bfe848aa695d78d0f1a8bcf6d06a9a6e)

```rust
struct Fahrenheit(f64);
struct Celcius(f64);
struct Kelvin(f64);


trait TemperatureUnit {
    fn to_kelvin(&self) -> Kelvin;
}

impl TemperatureUnit for Fahrenheit {
    fn to_kelvin(&self) -> Kelvin {
        Kelvin((self.0 + 459.67) * 5.0/9.0)
    }
}

impl TemperatureUnit for Celcius {
    fn to_kelvin(&self) -> Kelvin {
        Kelvin(self.0 + 273.15)
    } 
}

impl TemperatureUnit for Kelvin {
    fn to_kelvin(&self) -> Kelvin {
        Kelvin(self.0)
    }
}


fn main()
{
    println!("Hey");
}
```